# same page links in iphone mobile safari

Tags: html, hyperlink, mobile-safari

Mine is something of a newbie question which I'm hoping someone can shed some light on.

I have a table of contents on my page, with titles which link to sections further down the page.
the targets are created like this;
`<a name='appendix'>Appendix</a>`

and the links are created like this;
`<a href='#appendix'>Jump to Appendix</a>`

Now when you tap on the link in iphone safari, it takes you straight there no problem. However if you scroll back to the top, to the ToC, and tap the same link again, the browser does nothing.
Looking at the url I can see #appendix on the end and I assume that tapping the link again, the iphone believes its already at that link, since the url already has #whatever on the end.

Normally I'd be happy to leave it that, but the iPad, Android and Blackberry all behave as I'd expect, ie no matter where you are on the page or whether you'd tapped on the same link previously, they jump to the target section.

One thing I'm thinking about trying is embedding the whole page in a frameset so its url never changes, although being a noob I've no idea whether that'll even work.
Has anyone come across this before? Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: I'm having the same experience. It seems to be an issue on iOS version <= 4.1

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be an issue with iOS not you. If it has been working on all other devices I am afraid there is nothing you can do except report it to Apple. However, has your iPhone been acting crashy lately, and have you tried it on other iPhones?